# Data Error Cyclic Redundancy Check - 7 zip

Tags: unzip, zip, 7zip, crc

I have download a .zip file from the internet and now when I try to extract it using 7 Zip, it return back saying that a certain file has Data Error Cyclic Redundancy.
I also tried unzipping with the inbuilt Widows Unzipper, which is also showing an error extracting that file. Please help me.

Comment: The file has been corrupted, and the data cannot be extracted. There may have been an error in the download or an error at the source. You'll need to go back to the source and download it again, or find a different source. If you are using ftp, make sure it is in binary mode.

Comment: Ok man this was the same thing that I already knew. I don't know why this happens mostly when I down large zip files from Google Drive